# How to find the record if the field text be a sub string of any field text?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm searching for a Mongodb document by writing below command:

data seems like:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5b3d970398e9d099427896c3"),
  "role": "New Booking is there by abc",
  "date": "07/04/2018",
  "idaddress": "213.123.123.213",
  "booking": {
    "bedroom": 4,
    "bathroom": 6,
    "customer": "abc",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "provider": "provider1",
    "address": "brazil",
    "appt": "123456",
    "phone": "987654321"
  }
}
```

Query is:

```
 db.system.find({$text:{$search:"987654321"}})
```

this will show me the full record which it matches but I want that if I will entered `$search:"987"` then it will have to retrieve me matched records. What should be correction in my command can anyone help please.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try Regex search read about it

Comment: @kannan see the edit I also read about the regex but it doesn't satisfied the querry

Comment: what are the text-index settings for the field?

Comment: text-index for all the fields of the record @NiritLevi .

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Query to retrieve the documents which has phone numbers starting with `987`

```
db.collection_name.find({ "booking.phone" : {$regex : /^987/}})
```

Query to retrieve the documents which has phone numbers ending with `987`

```
db.collection_name.find({ "booking.phone" : {$regex : /987$/}})
```

Comment: Its fine @clementAmarnath but if i want to search customer then i have to write `find({ "booking.name" : {$regex : /string$/}})` but i want that the query in which there are number of fields and if user search any field it would not change like I above mentioned it will only change that what it want to search. Can it is possible.?

Comment: Try and see if OR condition helps, `$or` enables you to give a condition on `booking.name` and another condition on `booking.phone` and each condition can have a separate `$regex`

Comment: you mean to say i have to change `$text` will replace by the `$or` and `$search` will be replaced by the `$regex`. I tried it too but nothing get results please help me